# why scanf skips '\r' but reads '\n?'

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    char z;

    scanf( "%d", &x );
    scanf( "%d", &y );
    scanf( "%c", &z );
    printf( "%d %d %d", x, y, z );
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
1 2 10
```

*Why `scanf` reads `\n`, not `\r`? On pressing "Enter" inputs are `\r` and `\n`?*

`\r` --> (ASCII 13) and  `\n` --> (ASCII 10)

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: On Windows, newline is `\n` only, on Mac, newline is `\n\r`. For WIN7, forget the `\r`.

Comment: And on Windows if a file handle is open in text mode then the operating system will modify the input stream to convert '\r\n' to just '\n', so even if pressing enter does produce both characters the program will only see '\n'. The standard input is opened in text mode by default.

Comment: @haccks: On Windows the line ending is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdin` is defined to be a text stream ([C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.19.3.7) which by definition is terminated by only a newline (C99 7.19.2.2). This is complementary to stdout, printf uses only '\n' (not '\r') for a newline.

Assuming your standard input is non-standard for some reason, most platforms will only interpret a newline (pressing enter) as the '\n' character by default. This is often handled by the kernel and you would have to tell it to give you the carriage returns if you really wanted them.

Also, even if your platform does provide the '\r' character, it is possible that the '\n' is presented to stdin before '\r'. Try:

```
int x,y;
char z1, z2;

scanf("%d", &x);
scanf("%d", &y);
scanf("%c", &z1);
scanf("%c", &z2);

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x, y, z1, z2);
```

Comment: I think Amiga used the line ending \n\r. Nobody today does so that's... unlikely, let's say, to be the issue. Also there is a very common platform that doesn't use just \n, so the answer should cover why, on that platform the program doesn't see the \r. The reason is that text mode input makes certain guarantees about line endings.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` reads its data from standard input `stdin`. `stdin` is a *text* stream. Text streams automatically convert platform-specific line endings into just `\n`. This means that `\r\n` is automatically replaced with just `\n` by the inner workings of the stream. `scanf` never gets a chance to see that `\r`.

The same thing will happen in that platform if you read data from a file opened in text mode. Even though the file will contain `0xD 0xA` (`\r\n`) at the end of each string, `fscanf` will only see `\n` and not `\r`.

The only way to see `\r\n` on a platform that natively uses this combination as line ending marker is to use binary streams. Meanwhile, `stdin` is a opened as a text stream.

P.S. When you *write* data to a text stream, the reverse happens. You write `\n`, but the stream automatically replaces it with `\r\n`.